# How to get Emails of users via UID in Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the email IDs of the UIDs I have in DB, this is for the admin so that they may view which email IDs can be used to access an App's Admin panel.

How will I be able to that? I can't find anything related to this anywhere in the SDK Documentations.

The UIDs are of users that can login via Email and Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to put the emailId in the database too (can make nodes where child is emailId of each UID node,etc) while login, and then you can retrieve it using simple listeners.